# How to grab window's size without use of JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

How to detect what's the window's dimensions are without using JavaScript?

Comment: For what purpose, if you're not using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you just not use JavaScript or are you not able to use any scripting language(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Javascript in order to get that information and arrange for it to be transmitted to the server somehow. There's no other way to do it. (I'm assuming that you mean you want to know the size of the browser window that's displaying some HTML, and you want the window size information to be available to your php code on the server.)

*edit* — TJ correctly points out that Flash or Java or some other, less pedestrian client-side technology could also get the window information.  I assumed that if you're not willing to use Javascript, which would almost certainly be the easiest way to go, you wouldn't want to use anything else of the same sort, but that's definitely another option. The basic procedure would still be the same, however: send the page to the client, have the code gather the information you want, and the post it back somehow.

Comment: Yeah, JavaScript or some other technology on the client, like Java or Flash.